# MPAndroidChart compiling error with Proguard

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, proguard, mpandroidchart

When I include the latest library (2.0.7) using gradle and try to compile I get a warning from proguard, so I can't complie any more:

```
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart$DefaultFillFormatter: can't find referenced field 'boolean mStartAtZero' in program class com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
```

According to [docs](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedprogramclassmember) this is often an inconsistency while compiling, and I've tried to clean my project and recompile several times, but with same problem. Probably it's some problem with the chart library, since it's working fine with older gradle versions, like version 2.0.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem with MPAndroidChart library 2.0.7. Switching to the new 2.0.8 fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

That definitely looks like an inconsistency since the "mStartAtZero" field (which is obviously missing) **no longer exists** in the library version 2.0.7, but existed in earlier versions.

I suggest you completely remove the library from your project and then reimport the new version.

Comment: I tried this: I downloaded your example, removed the library and included from gradle instead, enabled minimize for debug and tried to run it on a device and I get exactly the same error about "mStartAtZero". So it must be something with the library. This is your own example, compiled for the first time. (You will need to add a progruard file, but it can be empty, same error)